# C++11 namespace scoping with functions

Tags: c++, function, c++11, scope, namespaces

Right now, I am coding a complex project in c++. I've simplified the example, where in a namespace I'm defining two functions, that both need each other.

```cpp
namespace Example {
   void foo()
   {
      bar();
   }

   void bar()
   {
      foo();
   }
}
```

Is there any way to fix my issue, without separating the functions from the namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward-declare inside a namespace exactly the same way you can do it at global namespace scope:

```
namespace Example {
   void bar();

   void foo()
   {
      bar();
   }

   void bar()
   {
      foo();
   }
}
```

However, as for any function, if these are functions defined in a header file shared between multiple translation units, then you would need to mark them `inline`. If they are functions declared and defined only in one `.cpp` meaning in one translation unit, then they should probably be marked `static`, so that other functions with the same name can be declared in other translation units without name clash and consequent ODR violations and UB.

Also, you can open and close a namespace as often as you want and in as many files and translation units as you want. E.g.

```
namespace Example {
    void foo();
    void bar();
}
```

in a header file and

```
#include<header.h>

namespace Example {
    void foo()
    {
       bar();
    }

    void bar()
    {
       foo();
    }
}
```

in a corresponding `.cpp` is also fine.